# Flask- Session (server-side cache) - CSRF attacks

Tags: flask, redis, csrf

From [testdriven.io](https://testdriven.io/blog/csrf-flask/)

> CSRF, which stands for Cross-Site Request Forgery, is an attack
> against a web application in which the attacker attempts to trick an
> authenticated user into performing a malicious action. Most CSRF
> attacks target web applications that use cookie-based auth since web
> browsers include all of the cookies associated with a particular
> domain with each request. So when a malicious request is made from the
> same browser, the attacker can easily make use of the stored cookies.

I decided to use Flask-Session, which is a Flask extension which enables the simple integration of a server-side cache, storing the user session data in the server.

Using this extension (storing user session on redis) is enough to prevent CSRF attacks ?

Comment: No, it is not, that's not what CSRF does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MartijnPieters. I really appreciate.

Comment: Note that this isn't really Flask specific. CSRF makes the user make a request they didn't mean to make, to the server. The server assumes they are talking to the legitimate user and that the request was _intentional_. Say, you use the session to identify the logged in user of a bank website. If an attacker can trick the user to transfer money to another account, it doesn't matter where the session data is stored.

Comment: For example, the attacker could send an image in an HTML email, but the link to the image is in reality a link to the bank website. If the user is logged into the bank site already, and so sends along the cookie from browser to site, the Flask-Session extension _still uses that cookie to identify the data in Redis to load_. The request looks to come from the user, regardless.

Comment: CSRF protection uses _extra data in the webpage_ that _must_ match information attached to the user account that is not available outside the browser page, and that changes each time you load a page that can trigger sensitive requests. That way the server at least knows the request came from a specific browser page that was just sent to the user first. An external attacker can't get that CSRF 'checksum' value, so the image-link-in-email trick wouldn't work because the CSRF checksum is missing or wrong.

Comment: I see your point. Thank you very much.
So, I need to add an extra layer of protection anyway, using something like https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html?highlight=csrfprotect#csrf-protection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Flask-Session doesn't protect against CSRF attacks, because CSRF attacks do not rely on session authentication, it relies on a *pre-existing connection between the browser and your site*. Flask-Session does not remove the connection between the user's browser and your session data, only where the session data associated with a user is stored.

All that Flask-Session lets you do is hide information you associate with a given user from outside eyes. But you still will need to be able to distinguish between user A and user B, so there is *still a cookie in the browser*, that tells your Flask server what data to load from Redis for that user. Without Flask-Session, any session data lives in the browser, with Flask-Session only a unique identifier is given to the browser.

CSRF attacks do not need to know what is is stored in the session, only that the session *exists*. A CSRF attack works when:

- The user can be tricked into sending a request to a site to do something that benefits the attacker
- The user has already been logged into the site, so the site sees request to do the desired action being sent from a client that has already been authenticated.

You mitigate CSRF attacks by requiring that every request that does something valuable is accompanied by a secret CSRF token, one that is **not stored in a session**. The browser must not allowed to keep CSRF values, so it will never use a CSRF token later on. You instead put the token in the HTML of the page or in other request and response headers. That way the server not only can trust that they have an authenticated user, but that the request is *fresh and wasn't generated by an attacker without access to the browser*.

If you are generating forms using WTForm, use the [Flask-WTF CSRF functionality](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html) to ensure the request came from a fresh web page. You can even use their API when not using forms, e.g. when using AJAX calls or hand-crafted forms.

You may want to read up on the [OWASP CSRF prevention page](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) to further understand how CSRF attacks work.